# debugging: new ssh connection could not be established but ping was ok on RHEL 6.3 (high cpu usage)

Tags: linux, rhel

One of my RHEL 6.3 build on vm raised an alert "virtual mechine cpu usage". I tried to connect to the vm using putty but the connection could not be established. There was no packet loss from ping. At last I had to reboot the vm and then everything was normal.

What was the problem and how can I find it?

Comment: look in the log files...

Comment: I go through with dmesg and /var/log/message but there i found nothing that i can relate with the issue.

Comment: Do you have crash installed ? Next time generate a kernel vmcore, which will help you to investigate.Server answering to ping, but not sshd, smells like a infinite loop with top priority which doesn't let the scheduler to give the hand to sshd.

Comment: crash-7.1.0-3.el6.x86_64 and
crash-trace-command-1.0-5.el6.x86_64 are installed. Now how can I investigate the issue?